# call multiple method on button touch event sequentially in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My requirement is that to call multiple method on button touch event sequentially in iphone. 
in my app their are many buttons and some methods are call on approx every button and some methods are call on specific buttons so that i want to call first general methods and after that the specific methods.

Comment: why dont you try nested method ?

Answer (score 0):

Just put 2 method calls underneath eachother?
Shouldn't be too hard.

Set the target for the button on some method like this:

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then call 2 methods sequentially in that method like this:

```
-(void)someMethod
{
    [self anotherMethod];
    [self yetAnotherMethod];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have one button callback where call several methods. You can link one button to several IBActions in interface builder. Or you can call the method

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

multiple times to set multiple actions.

Comment: is link methods call sequentially in interface builder?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
- (IBAction) btnActionl:(id) sender {
    [self actionForAllButtons];

    if ([sender isEqual:btn1]) {
        [self btn1Action];
        return;
    }

    if ([sender isEqual:btn2]) {
        [self btn2Action];
        return;
    }
}
```